# a simple selectionSort but run endlessly

Tags: javascript

I wrote a simple seletionSort as:

```
function selectionSort(arr) {
    let copyArr = [...arr];
    let newArr = [];
    while (copyArr) {
        minimum = Math.min(...copyArr);
        newArr.push(minimum);
        console.log("newArr", newArr);
        copyArr.splice(arr.indexOf(minimum), 1);
        console.log("copyArr", copyArr);
    }
    return newArr;
}
```

Unfortunately, when apply to `arr = [-7, 34, 27, 87, 21, 0, -11]`,it run endlessly and output:

```
newArr [ -11 ]
copyArr [ -7, 34, 27, 87, 21, 0 ]
newArr [ -11, -7 ]
copyArr [ 34, 27, 87, 21, 0 ]
newArr [ -11, -7, 0 ]
copyArr [ 34, 27, 87, 21, 0 ]
...
newArr [
-11, -7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0,  0, 0, 0,
... 752 more items
]
```

What's the problem?

Comment: `while (copyArr)` is always true.

Answer (score 3):

You have two main issues:

1. Arrays are always *truthy*, even when they're empty `[]`. Meaning that your while loop will continue to execute as `[]` will be evaluated as true when used in your `while` condition. You can change your condition to stop when the length is 0, which can be done by checking if the `.length` is truthy/falsy.
2. You're splicing the wrong index from your array. Currently, you're using `arr.indexOf(minimum)` on your array, but this will give you the index of your element before any elements from `copyArray` were removed. Meaning that the index of the element from `arr` doesn't match the index from `copyArray`. You can change this to find the index using `copyArray.indexOf()` to find the correct index of the minimum in copyArray

```js
function selectionSort(arr) {
  let copyArr = [...arr];
  let newArr = [];
  while (copyArr.length) {
    minimum = Math.min(...copyArr);
    newArr.push(minimum);
    console.log("newArr", newArr);
    copyArr.splice(copyArr.indexOf(minimum), 1);
    console.log("copyArr", copyArr);
  }
  return newArr;
}

console.log(selectionSort([4, 2, 10, 1]));
```

For a slightly more optimized solution, consider making a function to find the index of your minimum number, and then perform a swap. This way you won't need to iterate the array twice to find the minimum number and then the position of that number

```js
function findMinIndex(arr, start) {
  let minIdx = start;
  for(let i = start+1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] < arr[minIdx]) {
      minIdx = i;
    }
  }
  return minIdx;
}

function selectionSort([...arr]) {
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
    const minIdx = findMinIndex(arr, i); // get pos of min
    // Swap the two elements around
    const tmp = arr[i]; 
    arr[i] = arr[minIdx];
    arr[minIdx] = tmp;
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(selectionSort([4, 2, 10, 1]));
```

Comment: Your second solution changes the algorithm though. I'm pretty sure by making it a swap instead of a move it is no longer selection sort. Consider the efficiency of what it will do if the array is `[1,2,4,5,6,3]`

Comment: @CallumMorrisson swapping is a fairly [standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort#Implementations) operation to perform in selection sort. In both algorithms, if the arrays are already sorted, the best-case will be O(n^2), that's just a draw-back of selection sort.

Comment: My apologies, I misunderstood [the page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/selection-sort/) I was using as a reference.